# R - getting characters after symbol

Tags: r, regex, string

Im thinkging how can I get characters after the symbol in my dataframe.

```
14990349-1293
3935033-31
```

The result should be

```
1293
31
```

I have created

```
substr(df$id,1,as.integer(gregexpr('-',df$id)-1))
```

But this returns characters BEFORE the symbol. I cant find a way how to get only that after symbol -

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub(".*-", "", df$id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way by extending OP's attempt to use `substr/substring` can be as:

```
substring(df$id,as.integer(gregexpr('-',df$id))+1) #Detect '-'.Then take all from right of it
#[1] "1293" "31"
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("14990349-1293","3935033-31"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(strsplit(df$id, "-"), tail, 1)
 "1293" "31"
```